# Crash on switching segment control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a tableview with 4 segments on top. At the 1st segment I have loaded 76 rows, at segment 3 I have 4 rows, at 4th segment I have about 25 rows & there's nothing at segment 2. If the rows in each of the segment are not scrolled down and if all of them are at the top(i.e. the first row is visible out of the total number of rows for each segment) then no matter  how I switch the tabs, there won't be any crash.

But say for instance if at the 1st segment, I scrolled the rows down and then shifted to the 3rd segment, then there's a crash saying `fatal error: Index out of range`. Maybe due to mismatch in the number of rows on either tabs. But not sure about the fix. Hope somebody can help...

Comment: Do you which index is out of range? In which function does this happen? What's the call stack?

Comment: the crash happens at `cellForRowAt`

Comment: You need to post your code if you want some effective help

Comment: You have to reload the table after segment change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From this case i came to understand you are using same `UITableView` for three segments also i came to know your call `tableView.reloadData()` when you change segment the crash happen because of one segement have more data and other don't have when scroll tableView. *tableView's visble index positions not available in other segement's datasource because of that only you get crash* and solution for this you need to scroll to the 0th index if count greater than 0 then reload tableView

**when click on other segement before changing value to be populated scroll back to 0th index**

```
 if listArray.count > 0{
      let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
      self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .bottom, animated: false)
 }
```

**then change the value for `clickedSegement` to `listArray`**

then reload tableview

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

***Hope this will help you***

Comment: what does `listArray` indicate, @Ganesh Manickam ? does it indicate the array which has all the data of the rows..?

Comment: @GaneshManickam , while tap on segment control , is it not necessary to scroll the table at the top . why are you suggest this type of answer ?

Comment: @bvt , just follow the my answer , you will surelly able to prevent the crash .

Comment: Thanks, @Ganesh Manickam. Worked perfect...:)

Comment: yes `listArray` indicate array which contains data to be populated on `tableView` @bvt

Answer (score 0):

**Please check that below things are satisfied in your case OR not ?**

- While Changing the Segment Control , you have to **reload the tableView**
  with **NewDataSource**, and so you are going to change the UI so please
  put the code of **reloadData in main thread**.
- Make sure **numberOfRows** are maintained through Delegate method **while
  changing the segment Control**.
- And last but not least , another way to prevent the crash is that ,
  you can check the **indexPath.row < yourArray.count** in
  **cellForRowAtIndexPath Delegate Method**. This will **surelly prevent** the crash occures for **index out of range**.

Comment: @bvt you have to do nothing in that case . generally this will never happen that indexPath.row will increase then yourArray.count if you did perfect code . this line is just used for preventing the crash . the only one main thing in your case is that , reload the tableview in main thread . thats it , you dont have to scroll the tableview every time at 0 index.

Comment: @bvt , can you please show me your code what you have did while changing the segments